# Pi/product notation property applications problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, notation, factorial

I have recently attempted to simplify this
$$ P(n) = \prod_{v=2}^{n} (2 + \frac{2}{v^2 - 1}) $$

I have reached an answer (which is wrong) through the following steps:

rearranging what is inside the brackets

$$\prod_{v=2}^{n} (2 + \frac{2}{v^2 - 1})  = \prod_{v=2}^{n} (\frac{2v^2}{v^2 - 1}) $$
separating the equation into two
$$2^n \prod_{v=2}^{n} v^2 \cdot \prod_{v=2}^{n} (\frac{1}{v^2 - 1}) $$
using $ i = v^2$ to get rid of $v^2$ (change the lower bound too)
$$2^n \prod_{i=4}^{n} i \cdot \prod_{i=4}^{n} (\frac{1}{i - 1}) $$
using properties to simplify and get rid of pi notation
$$ 2^n(n! - 3!) \cdot \frac{1}{(n-1)!-2!}$$
which then simplifies to
$$ \frac{2^n(n! - 6)}{(n-1)! - 2} $$

I have since tested if my answer is right by plugging in different values of $n$ and it is definitely not right. I don't understand where I went wrong. Was there a property that I used was invalid? I also wasn't sure about the $i=v^2$ part and just assumed I could do that so maybe that's where I went wrong?

Comment: When you used $i=v^2$, then as $v$ varies from $2,3, \ldots ,n$, $i$ will take values $4,9,16, \ldots , n^2$. What it means is that, for example,  $i$ will not be taking values between $4$ and $9$.

Comment: ohhh that makes sense, maybe that's why this problem turns out wrong then... How would i rectify that mistake?

Comment: Minor: The fourth expression should start with $2^{n-1}$, since $v$ starts at $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in saying "Using $i=v^2$, and then letting $i$ run from $4$ to $n$.

That means that

- in the original expression, $v$ went from $2$ to $n$, taking the values $2, 3, 4,\dots, n$, which means that $v^2$ took the values $4, 9, 16, \dots, n^2$, but
- In the derived expression, $v^2$ takes the values $4, 5, 6, \dots, n$, which is not the same.

Also, a minor mistake you made is that if the product goes from $v=2$ to $v=n$, there are $n-1$ factors, so taking $2$ out of the product should result in $2^{n-1}$, not $2^n$.

---

It is generally not a good idea to make a switch to indices that will no longer be consequtive. Instead, I suggest you simplify your equation further, using a couple of things:

1. $\displaystyle\prod_{v=1}^n v^2 = \left(\prod_{v=1}^n v\right)^2$
2. $v^2-1=(v+1)(v-1)$

Comment: oh yes! the 2^n mistake i didn't even spot that. Also I am using the first property right now but I've never seen it. Is there a helpful resource out there that has a list of all the pi notation properties? I'm using a discrete math textbook and it doesn't have that property in it... and I can't seem to find a page on the internet where all the properties are listed?

Comment: @talkingpanda The first property is just an application of the fact that $$\prod a_i b_i=\left(\prod a_i\right)\left(\prod b_i\right),$$ which is a property you used yourself when separating the equation into two. Note that the property itself is basically just the commutativity of multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\prod_{v=2}^n\frac{2v^2}{v^2-1}&=2^{n-1}\prod_{v=2}^n\frac{v^2}{v^2-1}\\
&=2^{n-1}\color{red}{\prod_{v=2}^n\frac{v}{v-1}} \, \color{blue}{\prod_{v=2}^n\frac{v}{v+1}}\\
&=2^{n-1}\color{red}{\left[\frac{n}{1}\right]} \,\, \color{blue}{\left[\frac{2}{n+1}\right]}\\
&=2^n\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align*}

---

Added explanation:

$$\prod_{v=2}^{n}\frac{v}{v-1}=\frac{2}{1} \, \frac{3}{2}\, \frac{4}{3} \cdots \frac{n}{n-1}=\frac{n}{1}$$

Comment: OH you pulled that 2 out earlier!! and i didn't even think to use difference of squares wow. I'm still confused about how the red and blue changed from line 2 to 3?

Comment: @talkingpanda I have added some explanation that can help.

Comment: @NoChance i is a dummy variable! sorry for the confusion

Comment: @AnuragA oHHH omg thank you that makes so much sense

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and nice answer.